# Pre-populate Simulator with Twitter credentials

Tags: ios, twitter, ios-simulator

Is there any way to add Twitter accounts to the Simulator automatically? Due to a variety of factors I often have to 'Reset Content and Settings' on the simulator. This clears all Twitter account information. I then have to manually add multiple Twitter accounts. This is very time consuming and inefficient.